# React Docz error while generating development server: Error: Cannot find module 'typescript'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, documentation, docz

So I'm trying to make the documentation for my React project using react-docz but when I try to start the development server, I get the following error:

```
>$ C:\Users\me\project\node_modules\.bin\docz dev
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:892
  throw err;
  ^
Error: Cannot find module 'typescript'
Require stack:
>- C:\Users\me\project\node_modules\react-docgen-typescript\lib\parser.js
>- C:\Users\me\project\node_modules\react-docgen-typescript\lib\index.js
>- C:\Users\me\project\node_modules\docz-core\dist\index.js
>- C:\Users\me\project\node_modules\docz\bin\index.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:889:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:961:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\me\project\node_modules\react-docgen-typescript\lib\parser.js:26:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:961:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\me\\project\\node_modules\\react-docgen-typescript\\lib\\parser.js',
    'C:\\Users\\me\\project\\node_modules\\react-docgen-typescript\\lib\\index.js',
    'C:\\Users\\me\\project\\node_modules\\docz-core\\dist\\index.js',
    'C:\\Users\\me\\project\\node_modules\\docz\\bin\\index.js'   
  ]
}
>error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Cannot seem to figure this out. Does docz require typescript to work or? Need help plss!
Thanks!